# Finding the positions of multiple objects in an image, but only when they are next to each other

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Finding the positions of multiple objects in an image, but only when they are next to each other. So I would like to use parameters to decide whether 2 or 3 are next to each other and then get the coordinates.

At the moment I can only find one and it works. Code:

```
def diff(a, b):
    return sum((a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(a, b))

def g_c_o(c, _b):
    time.sleep(1)
    s_i_p = ''
    c_b_64 = _b.execute_script("return arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png').substring(21);", c)
    c_i = base64.b64decode(c_b_64)

    with open(r"canvas.png", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(c_i)

    with open("files/important.pickle", "rb") as f:
        d_r = pickle.load(f)
        if s_i_p == '' and d_r[10] is not None and d_r[10] != '':
            s_i_p = d_r[10]

    c_s_i = Image.open('canvas.png')
    i_s = c_s_i.size
    s_i = Image.open("findMe.png")
    w_s = s_i.size
    x0, y0 = w_s[0] // 2, w_s[1] // 2
    p = s_i.getpixel((x0, y0))[:-1]
    b = (100, 0, 0)
    c = []
    for x in range(i_s[0]):
        for y in range(i_s[1]):
            i_p_s = c_s_i.getpixel((x, y))
            d = diff(i_p_s, p)
            if d < b[0]:
                b = (d, x, y)
    x, y = b[1:]
    return [x, y]
```

And here the images, if this can help:

Image to find:

[image]

Find in:

[image]

And it works, i find this:

[image]

Can anyone tell me if I can find 2 or 3 that are next to each other and coordinates of them, not just the one?

Can anyone tell me if I can find 2 or 3 that are next to each other and coordinates of them, not just the one?

Comment: If you use **OpenCV** you can call `cv2.findContours()` and get the centroids and dimensions of each object... along with their colour and a measure of their circularity...

Comment: @MarkSetchell Do you maybe have an example for me?

Comment: Here's a start https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Comment: @MarkSetchell So far everything has worked out, now I can't find out the colors